# Cannot get a script file node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple doubt but can't figure it out. I am starting node js app,from a localhost location and through the response i am sending a html file. But its node loading the script file which is inside the html.

Node js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var ExpressPeerServer = require('peer').ExpressPeerServer;

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
    console.log("before redirection");
    res.sendfile('index.html'); });

var server = app.listen(9000);

var options = {
    debug: true
}

app.use('/api', ExpressPeerServer(server, options));

server.on('connection', function(id) { 
    console.log("In Server connection")
 });

server.on('disconnect', function(id) {
    console.log("server Disconnected")
 });
```

Html File

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.peerjs.com/0.3/peer.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ha ha this is Webrtc</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
    function webRtcInit() {
          alert("Inside Script")
    }
    $(document).on('ready', webRtcInit());
```

When i normally run the html file its loading the script file. But when i send the file through node js and load the script, I am getting the error , that it cannot get the script file, Why is this happening...?

Thanks

Comment: are the two files in the exact same directory? seems like it's probably a path issue

Comment: which version of express ur using?hope it's 4.x

Comment: @AbhishekPachal:Ya its 4.12 is there any problem with version..?

Comment: you should use app.route('/').get(function(req,res,next){...}); beacuse the syntax u r using is for express 3.x and its deprecated in 4.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am seeing  few problems in your code:

this renders your html page, similarly, you need one for `script.js`.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  
    console.log("before redirection");
    res.sendfile('index.html'); 
});
```

either specific:

```
app.get('/script.js', function(req, res, next) {  
    console.log("before redirection");
    res.sendfile('index.html'); 
});
```

or generic:

```
app.use(express.static('static'));   // now place your static files in the static folder.
```

unrelated to the problem at hand, but, in `script.js`, it is `webRtcInit` not `webRtcInit()` :

```
$(document).on('ready', webRtcInit);
```

Answer (score 4):

A node.js server does not serve any files by default (this is different that some other web servers).  So, any file that you want it to serve must have a route for it or some type of middleware that handles it.

So, your code does have a route for `/`, but when the browser parses the index.html file that you return from that route and then tries to load `script.js` from your node.js server, you don't have a route for that and the server will return a 404 (not found).

The solution is to create a route for `script.js`.  Since it's a static resource, you can probably use the express.static capability to serve all your static files.  You can read about serving static files in express [here](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html).